# Microserver + P420 RAID Controller

Tags: hard-drive, raid, hardware-raid

I just bought a MicroServer Gen8 for home laboratory with 4 x 3TB WD Red + 2 x 8GB ECC RAM + the ILO advanced license key.

My problem is that I can't make the P420 raid controller work with it.

I tried disabling the B120i raid controller, set it ti AHCI and Legacy with no success.

I updated all firmwares of the BIOS and nothing.

If I list the components in the IRQ device list I can't see my controller.

I saw people successfully installed the P420 raid controller with this MicroServer.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thans for your attention.

Comment: HP provides a number of utilities to assist with configuring their raid controllers. This link provides a configuration overview which includes your system - have you worked through this doc? http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c00729544

Comment: Hello, I can't see the raid controller, basically the MicroServer can't detect it, but I see the disks working and the raid controller loads correctly in another server (dl380 gen7). I tried to follow the steps in the "HP Array Configuration Utility" page but I can't see the server recognizes the raid controller.

Comment: What happens when you hit F5 during boot?

Comment: If the controller isn't found during boot then try to get to the ACU tool by hitting F10. See page 11 of that doc. Worst case build an ACU boot disk from an ISO image and boot from it. That tool is more capable than the standard bios based orca config tool and should be able to guide you through the process of setting it up.

Comment: I tried the ACU tool with not success. It only detects the B120i integrated one.

Comment: In that case I would contact HP support

Comment: Is there a way to upgrade the P420 firmware if it does not detect my raid card?

Comment: If you boot from the ACU iso there are diagnostic tools that should detect the card as long as its not a brick. If it can see it then you should be able to update the FW. If you don't want to contact HP - which really is a reasonable next step - then create a boot disk and try that route. http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_3c888073127c4c65b7bd8559eb

Comment: The first thing I done was contacting HP but the solution for him is that is not compatible, I see people successfully installing it but if it can't work propertly I preffer buy the P222 that is officially supported. Thanks all